# Polymer DomModule already defined

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, google-web-component

I'm building a website, where I'd use different polymer components, some of them multiple times.

My problem is that the  compiled code contains a

```
 customElements.define('dom-module', DomModule);
```

that throws

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry at CustomElementRegistry.value
```

I have no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: do you really create an element that is called `dom-module`?? obviously it is not propably possible to create element named like that

Comment: Nah, it's polymer that does that. My components are named different, that's not it.

Comment: I am getting the same error using slim.js in Chrome. When I run the same code in Mozilla, I get 'Error: A custom element with name 'slim-repeat' has already been defined.  webcomponents-lite.js:136:242'

Answer (score 2):

If you include polymer using two different paths in two different components, both of them gets executed and both tries to define dom-module, dom-if etc.

So check the networks panel for identical file names but different paths.

Example:

```js
/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js
and
/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js
```

Comment: I can confirm that I also had this problem and this was the reason